# $injector is not working in my test why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

-$injector is not working in my test why?-

Why it is not able to return my service?

foo.service.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooApp')
.factory('FooService', function () {

    var function1 = function function1(value) {
        return value;
    };

    return {
        function1 : function1
    };
});
```

my test(foo.service.spec.js)

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: FooService', function () {
beforeEach(module('fooApp'));

it('should...', inject(function(FooService) {
    expect(FooService.function1('...')).toEqual(...);
    ....

}));
....
});
```

When I evaluate FooService is undefined. Why ?

Error stacktrace:

```
...
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'FooService.function1')
...
```

new stacktrace error :

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fooApp due to:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$stateProvider
            .state')
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/app/auth/auth.js:15
    at invoke (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182)
    at runInvokeQueue (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4088)
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4097
    at forEach (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
    at loadModules (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120)
    at createInjector (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4004)
    at workFn (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2339)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=fooApp&p1=TypeError%3A%20'undefined'%20is%20not%20a%20function%20(evaluating%20'%24stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.state')%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fauth.js%3Fb8f7bccdf2d8f57e6d6f0c810e0d1c6f0d3df707%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4182)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4088)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4097%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A323)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4120)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3Febb86f089066f7089a249e390e64bcab67622158%3A4004)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fclient%2Fbower_components%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js%3Fb01a9cf8de7de4def103da067347cb07fe247c96%3A2339)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A1145%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2130%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2460%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2130%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2606%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2177%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F437512c57124d57f5ec77e2e82bfb4e3cdd15cce%3A2167
    at C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4118
    at forEach (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
    at loadModules (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120)
    at createInjector (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4004)
    at workFn (C:/_Projet/foo/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2339)
```

Comment: Did you add `foo.service.js` to Karma config into files section?

Comment: Yes  'client/components/**/*.js'

Comment: Is the C:/_Project/foo/client/app/auth/auth.js part of your project code? If so it looks like there is a dependency it requires that is not loaded into the module as part of test setup.

Comment: Yes it is part of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Angular mocks you should use underscore wrapping to resolve references as mentioned at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: FooService', function () {
    var FooService;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('fooApp');
        inject(function (_FooService_) {
            FooService = _FooService_;
        });
    });

....
});
```

**Note:** The previous version of this post had two `beforeEach()` calls. It is possible that the injection was running before the module was initialized. The edited version above moves the module initialization into a single `beforeEach()`.

You can also try another approach when using inject with the FooService being injected inline with your test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: FooService', function () {
    beforeEach(module('fooApp'));

    it('should...', inject(function(FooService) {
        expect(FooService.function1('...')).toEqual(...);
        ....

    }));
....
});
```

Comment: Please note the edit above with the `module('fooApp')` moved into the same `beforeEach()`

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using angular mocks and that FooService is actually being defined in the module prior to the test running?